# Rails - Multiple routes for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model which belongs to a Coin model. Is it possible to also use the Post model on its own and have a conditional in the controller that performs different actions based on if the route is /coins/posts or just /posts?

My routes are set up as

```
resources :posts
resources :coins do
  resources :posts 
end
```

Is it possible to some sort of check like

```
if (the current route is coin_posts_path)
  do x
elsif (the current route is posts_path)
  do y
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by checking presence of `coin_id` in the params:

```
if params[:coin_id]
  # nested action
else
  # standalone action
end
```

Comment: So in the model, how do I deal with the issue of setting the post to belongs_to :coin? It wouldn't always belong to a Coin in this case and I get a validation error when trying to create a new post that doesn't have a :coin_id

Comment: Nevermind. Just realized optional: true on the belongs_to works. Thanks.